# Magento2 Session Logsout when a person gets back from Payment Gateway

Tags: magento2, customer-session, logout, checkoutsession

I am facing a very weird Issue in my M2 Store, whenever a user gets back from payment gateway after successful transaction, user automatically logs out from the session and land back on cart page with successful txn message instead of success page.

I do not get this issue at every successful transaction, i have also noticed one more thing that this is happening from Chrome only, when i tried it from firefox i wasn't able to reproduce the issue.

Please guide what could be the possible reason for all this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: check logs in var/logs

Comment: facing the same issue , has someone found solution to this ??

Answer (score 0):

Most likely SameSite cookie issue. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26377) for more information. Also worth checking if there is an update for the payment module you are using.